# Populate a dropdown list via controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have to populate a `dropdown list` from a `List<string>` where the key is equal to the displayed value. I came up to extract the values, I did various tests to connect to the `View` but without success. Given the code that extracts the values:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PopulateDropDownList()
{
    try
    {
        var items = await DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBTelemetry>.GetDeviceIds();
        List<string> deviceids = new List<string>();

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            deviceids.Add(item.deviceId);
        }

        return View();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        throw (e);
     }
}
```

Can anyone help me for the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Model-View-Controller (MVC) framework, it is the job of the controller to pass the model to the view. Assuming that your list of strings, `items`, is correctly populated, the controller needs to pass it to the view.

First, you need to distinguish between actions and helper methods. Actions are public methods in the controller class. Actions can be accessed by the user via URL so in your case, http://application_name/controller_name/PopulateDropDownList would be a valid URL although this is meaningless to the user. Instead, you need to make `PopulateDropDownList` into a helper method like so:

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDropdownOptionsList()
{
  List<string> items = ...;
  return items;
}
```

Then, call the helper from a URL action such as

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> View()
{
  List<string> items = await GetDropdownListOptions();
  return View(items);
}
```

You may wish to look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs) for information on controller actions.

Second, the `View()` method constructs the view and sends it to the user but by default, it passes no data. You can pass your list of strings to the view by calling `View(items)` instead of `View()`. Then, your view would look like:

```xml
@model IEnumerable<string>

<select>
  @foreach (string item in Model)
  {
    <option value="@item">@item</option>
  }
</select>
```

The `@model IEnumerable<string>` directive specifies that the view expects a list of strings to be passed into the view. The `@foreach (string item in Model)` iterates through each string in the list and generates an `option` element for each one.

If you need to pass multiple data models into the view, you could use the `ViewBag` or `ViewData` objects. Simply add `ViewBag.Items = items;` to your `PopulateDropDownList` method like so:

```cs
private async void PopulateDropDownList()
{
  List<string> items = ...;
  ViewBag.Items = items;
}
```

Then your view would look like:

```xml
<select>
  @foreach (string item in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Items)
  {
    <option value="@item">@item</option>
  }
</select>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How is the controller method called? I have to use several different models on the same page..

Comment: You would want to call the `PopulateDropDownList` method as a helper method instead of an action. You would also want to use the `ViewBag` or `ViewData` objects. See my edits above.

Comment: And if I want to do the same in with a Web API how do I have to do?

Comment: All of this code should be transferrable to a Web API. Just remember that public methods are URLs that a client would be able to visit. For instance, if you wanted to define an API endpoint, http://app/api/GetIntegerList, that returns a list of integers, the method signature would be `public IEnumerable<int> GetIntegerList()` or `public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetIntegerList()` depending on whether the method is synchronous or asynchronous. See [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-controller) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option 1**

Retrieving Data from controller and accessing it from razor page.

MyController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PopulateDropDownList()
{
    var items = await 
                DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBTelemetry>.GetDeviceIds();
                List<string> deviceids = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
     deviceids.Add(item.deviceId);
    }
    ViewData["deviceids"] = deviceids;

    return View();
}
```

MyViewPage.cshtml

```
<select>
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
      @foreach (string deviceid in ((List<string>)ViewData["deviceids"]))
      {
        <option value="@deviceid">@deviceid</option>
      }
    </select>
```

**Option 2**

Retrieving and accessing data directly from razor page.

MyViewPage.cshtml

```
@Code
    var items =  DocumentDBRepository<CosmosDBTelemetry>.GetDeviceIds();
    List<string> deviceids = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in items)
     {
     deviceids.Add(item.deviceId);
     }
End Code

<select>
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
  @foreach (string deviceid in deviceids)
  {
    <option value="@deviceid">@deviceid</option>
  }
</select>
```

Comment: And in how do i connect the page with the controller method? Thanks a lot. I choos Option 1. Simone

Comment: @Simone Spagna Just make Target Page and Controller method have same name. i.e (PopulateDropDownList.cshtml).

Comment: It isn't my case. The dropdown list is in a complex page that uses more than one models.

Comment: And if I want to do the same in with a Web API how do I have to do?